# Solve this simple polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rational-functions

$$\text{Problem: }{x^3-x^2-x-2 \over x^2 + x - 6}$$
My textbook was able to come up with $(x-2)(x^2+x+1)$
$$\text{Textbook: }{(x-2)(x^2+x+1) \over (x-2)(x+3)}$$

I've tried grouping and using the first and last 3 terms as trinomial but it doesn't work. How do I get that solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's the question? Put the fraction in least terms?

Comment: @IanColey well, if I got (x-2). I could eliminate them. I'm trying to solve a limit problem

Comment: Which limit?$\,$

Comment: Question unclear

Comment: It is clear, I'm only trying to figure out how I can factor out the problem so that I could obtain x-2

Comment: The limit problem holds little relevance to the question

Comment: @MouseHello : The basic fact from algebra that LAcarguy identifies in his posted answer below is something that the vast majority of students forget.  I say to a student: "If you plug a number into a polynomial and get zero, that tells you something about how to factor the polynomial", and then see if the student remembers what that conclusion is.  More than 90% of the time, they don't remember it.  But then they admit to recalling it once reminded of what it says.  It plays a basic role in calculus, in finding limits of difference quotients.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My brain is extremely fuzzy right now it's 2 am lol --cramming for exam

Comment: The simple "grouping" technique isn't going work well on the numerator polynomial; it's just a method that works in some cases.  Looking for a "zero" and using the Factor Theorem, as **LAcarguy** shows below, is more certain to work, if factors are there to be found.  (Since this _is_ part of a limit problem [ $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \ $ ? ], the factorization of the quadratic polynomial in the denominator is giving you a hint about what to try...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner So how do you come up with $(x^2+x+1)$?

Comment: Have you had polynomial or synthetic division?  (That should have come up somewhere in pre-calculus.)  Dividing $ \ x-2 \ $ into $ \ x^3 - x^2 - x + 2 \ $ does give a quotient of $ \ x^2 + x + 1 \ $ ( or using "2" in synthetic division on $ \ 1 \ -1 \ -1 \ -2 \ $ produces $ \ 1 \ 1 \ 1 \ 0 \ $ ) .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thank you so much, I'll look into synthetic division!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cubic polynomial, by checking the value of it at some integer values of $x$ like $x = 2$ then $2^3 - 2^2 - 2 - 2 = 0$. This means $x - 2$ is a factor, and using long division you get the other factor. For the quadratic expression, you also have $2$ is a root and also $-3$ is also a root. Then it can be factored as $(x - 2)(x + 3)$.

Comment: I don't get it. How can you know x-2 is a factor? And if you know it's a factor, how can you come up with x^2+x+1

Comment: @MouseHello: you carry out the long division.

Comment: What do you mean by long division? Do you mean $x^3-x^2-x-2 \over (x-2)$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division (or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division)

Comment: @MouseHello: yes.